# Jquery Content Slider: Add an error class to a navigation menu that corresponds to empty section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that is broken up into a Jquery Content slider (i.e. vertical tabs). 
This breaks the form into manageable chunks for the user to fill in.

At the moment, if the user forgets to fill in a field, an `error` class is applied to that section of the form. However, if that section is not visible, the user won't see the error styling.

I want to add the error class to the corresponding part of the vertical tab navigation menu. How can I do this?

The Jquery code that is used to flip between the sections is as follows:

```
$(".taptabs li").live('click', function() {
     $(this).parent().parent().parent().$('.pages .page').hide().eq($(this).index()).show().addClass("animated").addClass(mode).addClass("fadeInLeft");
});
```

(`Taptabs` is the name of the navigation list. Each section of the form has a class of `page` Each section is also in the HTML element of `<section>` ).

I thought this would work to make the error message appear on the navigation:

```
  $(".changing-room").submit(function () {
      var isFormValid = true;
      $("input.required").each( function () {
          if ( $.trim( $(this).val() ).length === 0 ) {
              $(this).parent().addClass("error");
              var menulink = $(this).closest('section').index();
              $('.tapnav li').index(menulink).addClass('error'); 

              isFormValid = false;
          }
       });
   });
```

In this code, when an Input is left empty, the closest `Section` tag is located (This section tag holds that particular section of the form). The index of that section tag is calculated and then it is applied to the corresponding `LI` of the Nav menu. However, it doesn't seem to work, it actually breaks all the code!

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/aRjhz/4/)

Comment: Live is no more.  Please use .on()

   http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out:

```
$(".MY-WRAPPER-CLASS").submit(function () {
    var isFormValid = true;
    $("input.required").each(function () {
      if ($.trim($(this).val()).length === 0) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("error");
         var menulink = $(this).closest('section').index(); //Note 1
        $('.tapnav li').eq(menulink).addClass('error');  //Note 2

        isFormValid = false;
      }
      else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("error");
      }
    });

  });
```

Note 1: We use `.closest()` to find the parent `<section>` tag of the empty form element.
We then use `.index()` to find the index value of the section.
It is then assigned to a variable called menu link.

Note 2: We then use `.eq()` to target the menu link that has the same index value as the section.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I guess.  One is you don't let them go to the next tab until they finished their work on the current tab.  That's option #1 below.  Option #2 as you state is to style the tab somehow so they can see they need to return to it.  See #2 below.

**#1:**

In your click event (use .on() not .live()) wrap the containing code in this:

```
if(!$('.error').length){
   //All the code you have in your event now should be here - that is, there are no errors they can proceed.
} else {
  //else is optional.  Here you could do whatever you want to tell the user - "no, you can't move on because you have a validation issue.  Here is a suggestion:
  alert('You have errors! ' + someerrorvar);
}
```

**#2**

Again, as above use a .on() event instead of .live() because .live() is no more.

I'm going to make an assumption that there's a class that indicates a certain tab is the active tab.  We'll call that class 'tater' for lack of a true class name.  If so, just use that thusly:

//At the beginning of your event, before you pull the switch
$('.tater').addClass('incomplete');

Then use incomplete to style that tab as desired.

**Final Thoughts:**

I would go with #1.  It's clear to the user that, hey, something's not right here and we need to fix it.  Be sure and put the validation text clearly in the user's face.